# How to test that I am validating that a relationship has at least one entry in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I have a has_many relationship that should always have at least one entry in it.  If there aren't any entries, it's invalid.

How do I test that validation in RSpec?

Closest I've gotten is `it { should validate_length_of(:fees).is_at_least(1) }`, but that's intended for strings and won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that you have an instance of your class like `described_class_object`, you can do:

```
context 'when there are no fees' do
  it 'is not valid' do
    described_class_object = described_class.build(...some params...)
    described_class_object.fees = []
    expect(described_class_object).to_not be_valid
  end
end
```

Comment: So there aren't any rspec matchers for this scenario.  Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a user has_many books relationship.
User is set to a user object

```
it { user.books.count.should be >= 1 }
```

with expect in rspec

```
it { expect(user.books.count).to be >= 1 }
```